# GA doesn't see dynamics title tag

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, title

I'm use helmet for setup dynamic title, but google analytics doesn't show me dynamic title in reports.

```
<IntlMessages id="sidebar.tobaccoLineDescription">
          {(title) => (
            <Helmet>
              <title>
                 {title} {line && line.name}
              </title>
              <meta property="og:title" content={title + ' ' + line && line.name} />
              <meta property="og:description" content={('Описание ' + (line && line.name) + ' линейки')} />
              <meta 
              name="description" 
              content={('Описание ' + (line && line.name) + ' линейки')} />
            </Helmet>
          )}
        </IntlMessages>
```

Should I change code? Or setup some GA settings?
I'm afraid what the google search bot doesn't see dynamic tags too. (I don't know how to check it).

Do you have a suggestion for me?

Link for example with dynamic titles.
http://hookahscope.com/app/tobaccos/line/5f4582a998341624785e6a55

Google analytics code in MainApp:

```
ReactGA.initialize('UA-XXX');
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your Google analytics code.

Comment: make sure you're calling analytics function like `ga('send'...)` after the specific page is rendered. You might find this guide useful https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

Comment: @DaImTo added ga code

Comment: I see the issue. But how to implement instead if write ga send to each page?